# Deploying Django and Angular 2 on Heroku

Tags: python, django, angular, heroku

I am at a bit of a roadblock. Under one GitHub repository, I have two services. A **Django** API, and an **Angular 2** application (forgive me if any of my vocabulary isn't aaccurate). I am trying to use **Heroku** to accomplish hosting this. My current Procfile looks like so:

```
web: node frontend/server.js
api: gunicorn platform/Minieco/wsgi.py
```

However, when I build through Heroku's website, I get the following output:

```
-----> Python app detected
-----> Installing requirements with pip
-----> Discovering process types
   Procfile declares types -> api, web
-----> Compressing...
   Done: 47.2M
-----> Launching...
   Released v7
   https://minieco.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

It detects the app as Python, when really only the API is. Maybe this isn't the issue, but it stood out to me. Either way, I get an Application Error when I visit the website, what are the correct steps to take in order to run both of these services side-by-side?

EDIT:

I want the Django API and the Angular frontend to be independent of each other like server and client. I am going to use gunicorn to server django, and node express to server Angular. Assuming this works, how can I get Heroku to do this?

Comment: Does everything work locally after you build the angular project ?

Comment: @Andresson running `npm install` in the same package as my `package.json` starts a chain reaction that results in running `ng build --aot -prod`and then `node server.js`. Its throwing an error about not having express... but I installed it when I typed `npm install` because it's in the `package.json` right?

Comment: Uhm, I dont think i understand you correctly. Are you using both node+express server and also Django ?

Comment: @Andresson I followed [this](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-cli-deployment-host-your-angular-2-app-on-heroku-3f266f13f352) to get to where I am now. I am trying to run an API via Django/Gunicorn. The thing is, I am trying to also run an angular application to serve as the frontend. I know very little bout node and express, I was under the impression you needed both?

Comment: NoNo, Node express serves the same purpose as Django. Its a Rest API. So the good news are, you dont need Node+express to serve angular. 
If you go into your angular project folder and run `ng build --prod` a new dist folder with bundled js files will appear. + 1 html file.  If the build process worked without errors u should be able to open this html page in a browser.

Comment: @Andresson how would I get Heroku to do this for me? Are you saying use gunicorn to serve both the django api and the angular frontend?